# Account Record Access Issue

Tags: profile, sharing-rule, role-hierarchy, admin

[image: Account Sharing Rules]I have a user with custom profile and role. The account is private in OWD and Read, Create, Edit access in profile. And we also have sharing rules on account where if records owner is in group, the user can access the record.

So the issue is when I login with that particular user and check with account id (where account owner is in the group as per sharing rule), I am getting insufficient privileges. Please let me know why he cant access this particular record?

Comment: Is the User you are logging in with is in the Group?

Comment: @jayant yes,he is the user

Comment: What do you mean by *login from group*? If the OWD is private, no other User other than record owner can view that record unless shared. And if your records are shared with a public group, then the User who is not an owner, if s/he need to have access to that record, need to be in the public group.

Comment: Can you share a screen shot of your sharing rule?

Comment: @Jayant Das ,We have a public group where account owner and the user is in it. and the sharing rule is if owner is in group the group members can access the record.even if account is private in owd, sharing rules will override it and how ever he has read access on.that mean he can access records with respect of sharing rules. the problem is,even if he is in group, he couldn't able to see. please suggest me

Comment: @Daniel Hoechst, Please check the screen shot of account sharing rules. the owner and user who is trying to access record are available in group

Comment: You seem to have two groups here (Nex-Everyone and Nex-Tech Support) and that you have a owner based sharing rule. So to which group does the logging in User belong to? And does the Account in question here is owned by the User who belongs to Nex-Everyone group?

Comment: When you click the Sharing button on the account record, do you see the shares? You can only see the button in Classic.

Comment: @jayant Das, He belongs to both groups. and the owner also available in both.

Comment: @ Daniel Hoechst yeah , isee the shares but it not showing those group. it hink we have to add them by clicking on add button